# Opening a specific Android home screen page

Tags: android

I am trying to create an Android service that causes a specific home screen page to open when the Droid is placed in the Car Dock instead of having it open the Car Home application. I cannot find any reference to how to specify a home screen page other than the center page that always gets displayed when pressing the Home button by using CATEGORY_HOME. Does anyone know how I would have my application open a specific page?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [**That Stupid Car Dock App**](http://alldroid.org/viewtopic.php?f=207&t=607) post, they seem to have code showing how launch the intent and switch between the dock state.

You can launch `startActivity` to load your application when dock state is set to `Intent.EXTRA_DOCK_STATE_CAR`

Hope this helps.